# How to install CiviCRM patch (5.7.2 to 5.7.5) on Drupal 7.64 - is my file directory writeable?

Tags: drupal, upgrade

Currently running Drupal 7.64 and got a notification that I need to install a security patch on CiviCRM. Currently running CiviCRM 5.7.2 and need to install 5.7.5.

Apologies in advance if this question seems a bit unintelligent - but completely beyond my scope!

I read through the [instructions in the CiviCRM Documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/drupal7/) and had one question in particular:

```
Ensure that your Drupal files directory is writeable by the webserver.
```

Is there a way of doing this through cPanel? I have no idea how to access anything command line-related...

I've updated Drupal before (e.g. from 7.61 to 7.64), not sure if that gives an indication of whether my file directory is writeable?

The rest of the instructions seem pretty straight forward... but is there anything else I need to be wary of? Always a bit hesitant with installing updates for the first time, so just making sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cpanel it's described in more detail at https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/76Docs/File+Manager#FileManager-Modifyfileorfolderpermissions

but briefly open the icon called File Manager and right-click on the folder and choose permissions.

In most shared hosting setups "writable by the webserver" means the user column has write access. Here "Drupal files" most likely means the "sites/default/files" subfolder.

But if you're upgrading and civi was working before it almost certainly has the right permissions already.

If you make backups first you'll usually be safe no matter what happens.